# How to list props.data in <textarea/> using reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, react-props

I am trying to set data to textarea as props.data and data is array 
ex.

data = [abc, cder,erdf,hhdh]

Comment: Is data `string` or `object`?

Answer (score 0):

Textarea will not render array. It will require string data which can be displayed. So, parse your array to a string and then pass it to textarea.

```js
let data = ["abc", "cder", "erdf", "hhdh"].toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: this will cause problem while loading same data from this.state.data

Comment: You can parse the data before passing it to the textarea. In other scenario's you can easily update the state.